# Show data in ASP.NET html table

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am writing an ASP.NET page which reads data from a database and needs to show it in a table. For some reason, I don't want to use the gridView.

**How do I show the data in a table on the HTML page?**

This is my C# code:

```
        SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection);
        SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
        thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from Test";
        thisConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string Name = reader.GetString(1);
            string Pass = reader.GetString(2);                   
        }

        thisConnection.Close();
```

This is my ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/test.master" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server"  ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder">
    <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" >
        <tr align="left" style="background-color:#004080;color:White;" >
            <td> ID </td>                        
            <td> Name </td>            
            <td>Pass</td>                        
        </tr>

        **<%--Need the while output into here--%>**

    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: try using this

http://projectpeeker.com/2018/01/17/view-values-table-without-using-grid-view-asp-net/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically use the classic ASP\PHP\Spaghetti code approach.

First of all, place your code in one public method that returns a `string`.
The method:

```
public string getWhileLoopData()
{
        string htmlStr = "";
        SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection);
        SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
        thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from Test";
        thisConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string Name = reader.GetString(1);
            string Pass = reader.GetString(2);
            htmlStr +="<tr><td>"+id+"</td><td>"+Name+"</td><td>"+Pass+"</td></tr>"                   
        }

        thisConnection.Close();
        return htmlStr;
}
```

Then you can use the `<%=getWhileLoopData()%>` tag in ASP.NET that is equal to `<%Response.Write(getWhileData())%>`

It should look something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/test.master" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server"  ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder">
    <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" >
        <tr align="left" style="background-color:#004080;color:White;" >
            <td> ID </td>                        
            <td> Name </td>            
            <td>Pass</td>                        
        </tr>

        <%=getWhileLoopData()%>

    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

There is also the option to use an repeater control and bind the data from your DB to an Item Template of your liking.

Comment: can u pls give the full solution??or any example ? or example link??i can't get you. Thanks. But i need to load the output into page_loader

Comment: it's showing error when usingt the <%#getWhileLoopData()%> in html page.

Comment: just use <%Response.Write(getWhileLoopData())%> or <%=getWhileLoopData()%>sorry about that ..

Comment: sorry for bothering. Both showing error.I am using asp.net 4.0.ViewDataBaseDetail.getWhileLoopData()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: sorry again .. change the access modifier from private to public

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use repeater control and create your html table structure in repeater.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" >
<HeaderTemplate>
<tr class="Header">
<td>
ID
</td>
<td>
Name
</td>
<td>
Pass
</td>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td>
<%# Eval("ID")%>
</td>
<td>
<%# Eval("Name")%>
</td>
<td>
<%# Eval("Pass")%>
</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

bind repeater as same as you bind gridview

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you put the `runat="server"` attribute on your HTML table, you can actually programmatically access it in your code-behind. It's quite a powerful feature.

It's definitely not the best solution, but it's a very cool feature no one knows about.

Comment: could you please give an example??

Answer (score 0):

add 3 `literal` controls to your asp page put them in the `tr` below the title `td`s, and then:

```
while (reader.Read())
    {
        int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
        string Name = reader.GetString(1);
        string Pass = reader.GetString(2);  
        literalID.text += id.ToString();
        literalName.text += Name.ToString();
        literalPass.text += Pass.ToString();
    }
```

this is the easiest solution I know, but it's not neat.
here's the `html` code:

```
<tr align="left" style="background-color:#004080;color:White;" >
    <td> ID </td>                        
    <td> Name </td>            
    <td>Pass</td>                        
</tr>
<tr align="left" style="background-color:#004080;color:White;" >
    <td><asp:Literal ID="literalID" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>                        
    <td><asp:Literal ID="literalName" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>            
    <td><asp:Literal ID="literalPass" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>   
</tr>
```

Comment: can you please help me to write the html part?? because i can't get you , how to write the html part.

Comment: Sorry, it's showing all data into a single row.But i need multipul row.I mean all available row in database.

Comment: @riad if you have gotten the point, you can dynamically add table rows and columns and assign each row a value, if you still have trouble tell me to add the code.

Comment: Down-voted because doesn't this just concatenate the strings of every database row into a *single* table row?!

Answer (score 0):

In this solution  , all HTML tags create in client Side and client have to render this processes instead of server.
this is a better idea and give best performance for your server
then use this code:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" 
 ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder">
     <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" >
         <tr align="left" style="background-color:#004080;color:White;" >
             <td> ID </td>                        
             <td> Name </td>            
            <td>Pass</td>                        
         </tr>

       <% if(dt != null && dt.rows.count>0){
              foreach(var item in dt.rows)
                 {%>
                   <tr>
                      <td><%=item["ID"]%></td>
                      <td><%=item["Name"]%></td>
                      <td><%=item["Pass"]%></td>
                   </tr>
                  <%}
                }%>

     </table> </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.