# repeat header row table in each print page in google chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

I found this solution that prints a header in each page page in google chrome
[Show data in ASP.NET html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860490/show-data-in-asp-net-html-table)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <body>
<table class="print t1"> <!-- Delete "t1" class to remove row numbers. -->
  <caption>Print-Friendly Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Column Header</th>
      <th>Column Header</th>
      <th>Multi-Line<br/>Column<br/>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>Multiple<br/>lines of<br/>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  </body>
     </html>
       <style>
       /* THE FOLLOWING CSS IS REQUIRED AND SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED. */
       div.fauxRow {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
         width: 100%;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
}
table.fauxRow {border-spacing: 0;}
table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td > table.print {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td > table.print > caption {caption-side: top;}
.noBreak {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.noBreak:before, .noBreak:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
}
.noBreak:after {margin-top: -594mm;}
.noBreak > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:100%;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
/*table.print > thead {white-space: nowrap;}*/ /* Uncomment if line-wrapping causes problems. */
table.print > tbody > tr {page-break-inside: avoid;}
table.print > tbody > .metricsRow > td {border-top: none !important;}

/* THE FOLLOWING CSS IS REQUIRED, but the values may be adjusted. */
/* NOTE: All size values that can affect an element's height should use the     
  px unit! */
table.fauxRow, table.print {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
   /* THE FOLLOWING CSS IS OPTIONAL. */
  body {counter-reset: t1;} /* Delete to remove row numbers. */
.noBreak .t1 > tbody > tr > :first-child:before {counter-increment: none;} /*    
  Delete to remove row numbers. */
.t1 > tbody > tr > :first-child:before { /* Delete to remove row numbers. */
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  counter-increment: t1 1;
  content: counter(t1);
}
table.fauxRow, table.print {
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Georgia; /* Try to use fonts that don't get 
  bigger when printed. */
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto; /* Delete if you don't want table to be centered. */
}
table.print {border-spacing: 0;}
table.print > * > tr > * {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
table.print > * > :first-child > * {border-top: 2px solid black;}
table.print > thead ~ * > :first-child > *, table.print > tbody ~ * > :first-
child > * {border-top: none;}
table.print > * > tr > :first-child {border-left: 2px solid black;}
table.print > thead {vertical-align: bottom;}
table.print > thead > .borderRow > th {border-bottom: none;}
table.print > tbody {vertical-align: top;}
table.print > caption {font-weight: bold;}
</style>
 <script>
 (function() { // THIS FUNCTION IS NOT REQUIRED. It just adds table rows for       
 testing purposes.
var rowCount = 100
  , tbod = document.querySelector("table.print > tbody")
  , row = tbod.rows[0];
         for(; --rowCount; tbod.appendChild(row.cloneNode(true)));
        })();
      (function() { // THIS FUNCTION IS REQUIRED.
       if(/Firefox|MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
  var formatForPrint = function(table) {
    var noBreak = document.createElement("div")
      , noBreakTable =   
     noBreak.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).
   appendChild(table.cloneNode())
      , tableParent = table.parentNode
      , tableParts = table.children
      , partCount = tableParts.length
      , partNum = 0
      , cell = table.querySelector("tbody > tr > td");
    noBreak.className = "noBreak";
    for(; partNum < partCount; partNum++) {
      if(!/tbody/i.test(tableParts[partNum].tagName))
        noBreakTable.appendChild(tableParts[partNum].cloneNode(true));
    }
    if(cell) {
      noBreakTable.appendChild(cell.parentNode.parentNode
      .cloneNode()).appendChild(cell.parentNode.cloneNode(true));
      if(!table.tHead) {
        var borderRow = document.createElement("tr");
        borderRow.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).colSpan="1000";
        borderRow.className = "borderRow";
        table.insertBefore(document.createElement("thead"), 
      table.tBodies[0]).appendChild(borderRow);
      }
    }
    tableParent.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"), 
    table).style.paddingTop = ".009px";
    tableParent.insertBefore(noBreak, table);
  };
      else
     var formatForPrint = function(table) {
    var tableParent = table.parentNode
      , cell = table.querySelector("tbody > tr > td");
       if(cell) {
      var topFauxRow = document.createElement("table")
        , fauxRowTable =  
       topFauxRow.insertRow(0).insertCell(0).appendChild(table.cloneNode())
        , colgroup =  
      fauxRowTable.appendChild(document.createElement("colgroup"))
        , headerHider = document.createElement("div")
        , metricsRow = document.createElement("tr")
        , cells = cell.parentNode.cells
        , cellNum = cells.length
        , colCount = 0
        , tbods = table.tBodies
        , tbodCount = tbods.length
        , tbodNum = 0
        , tbod = tbods[0];
      for(; cellNum--; colCount += cells[cellNum].colSpan);
      for(cellNum = colCount; cellNum--; 
     metricsRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).style.padding = 0);
      cells = metricsRow.cells;
      tbod.insertBefore(metricsRow, tbod.firstChild);
      for(; ++cellNum < colCount; 
     colgroup.appendChild(document.createElement("col")).style.width = 
      cells[cellNum].offsetWidth + "px");
      var borderWidth = metricsRow.offsetHeight;
      metricsRow.className = "metricsRow";
      borderWidth -= metricsRow.offsetHeight;
      tbod.removeChild(metricsRow);
      tableParent.insertBefore(topFauxRow, table).className = "fauxRow";
      if(table.tHead)
        fauxRowTable.appendChild(table.tHead);
      var fauxRow = topFauxRow.cloneNode(true)
        , fauxRowCell = fauxRow.rows[0].cells[0];
      fauxRowCell.insertBefore(headerHider, 
       fauxRowCell.firstChild).style.marginBottom = -
         fauxRowTable.offsetHeight - borderWidth + "px";
      if(table.caption)
        fauxRowTable.insertBefore(table.caption, fauxRowTable.firstChild);
      if(tbod.rows[0])
        fauxRowTable.appendChild(tbod.cloneNode()).appendChild(tbod.rows[0]);
      for(; tbodNum < tbodCount; tbodNum++) {
        tbod = tbods[tbodNum];
        rows = tbod.rows;
        for(; rows[0]; tableParent.insertBefore(fauxRow.cloneNode(true), 
       table).rows[0].cells[0].children[1].appendChild(tbod.cloneNode())
     .appendChild(rows[0]));
      }
      tableParent.removeChild(table);
    }
    else
      tableParent.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"),   
     table).appendChild(table).parentNode.className="fauxRow";
  };
      var tables = document.body.querySelectorAll("table.print")
      , tableNum = tables.length;
    for(; tableNum--; formatForPrint(tables[tableNum]));
       })();
         </script>
```

but when I apply my table it's not working (Note : I use a repeater in my table because I want to get the data from data base )

```
   <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
          <body>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" >
         <HeaderTemplate>
            <thead>
            <tr class="Header">
            <th>
           ID
            </th>
              <th>
               Name
            </th>
               <th>
            Pass
              </th>
       </tr>
          </thead>
         </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
        </tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>
           <%# Eval("stat_date")%>
         </td>
              <td>
      <%# Eval("stat_leger")%>
        </td>
        <td>
     <%# Eval("stat_amount")%>
    </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
    </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
       </body>
 </html>

    <style>
       /* THE FOLLOWING CSS IS REQUIRED AND SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED. */
div.fauxRow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
table.fauxRow {border-spacing: 0;}
table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td > table.print {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: top;
}
      table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td > table.print > caption {caption-side:  
       top;}
         .noBreak {
         float: right;
           width: 100%;
          visibility: hidden;
       }
       .noBreak:before, .noBreak:after {
        display: block;
      content: "";
       }
         .noBreak:after {margin-top: -594mm;}
       .noBreak > div {
           display: inline-block;
         vertical-align: top;
           width:100%;
           page-break-inside: avoid;
            }
         /*table.print > thead {white-space: nowrap;}*/ /* Uncomment if line-              
        wrapping causes problems. */
      table.print > tbody > tr {page-break-inside: avoid;}
      table.print > tbody > .metricsRow > td {border-top: none !important;}

      /* THE FOLLOWING CSS IS REQUIRED, but the values may be adjusted. */
       /* NOTE: All size values that can affect an element's height should 
      use the px unit! */
      table.fauxRow, table.print {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
      }

    /* THE FOLLOWING CSS IS OPTIONAL. */
      body {counter-reset: t1;} /* Delete to remove row numbers. */
    .noBreak .t1 > tbody > tr > :first-child:before {counter-increment: 
      none;} /* 
     Delete to remove row numbers. */
 .t1 > tbody > tr > :first-child:before { /* Delete to remove row numbers. */
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  counter-increment: t1 1;
  content: counter(t1);
}
     table.fauxRow, table.print {
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Georgia; /* Try to use fonts that don't get   
       bigger when printed. */
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto; /* Delete if you don't want table to be centered.    
     */
      }
    table.print {border-spacing: 0;}
   table.print > * > tr > * {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
   }
   table.print > * > :first-child > * {border-top: 2px solid black;}
  table.print > thead ~ * > :first-child > *, table.print > tbody ~ * >  
      :first-  
  child > * {border-top: none;}
   table.print > * > tr > :first-child {border-left: 2px solid black;}
   table.print > thead {vertical-align: bottom;}
   table.print > thead > .borderRow > th {border-bottom: none;}
   table.print > tbody {vertical-align: top;}
     table.print > caption {font-weight: bold;}
        </style>

       <script>
(function () { // THIS FUNCTION IS NOT REQUIRED. It just adds table rows for   
       testing purposes.
             var rowCount = 100
         , tbod = document.querySelector("table.print > tbody")
           , row = tbod.rows[0];
     for (; --rowCount; tbod.appendChild(row.cloneNode(true)));
      })();

      (function () { // THIS FUNCTION IS REQUIRED.
    if (/Firefox|MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
        var formatForPrint = function (table) {
            var noBreak = document.createElement("div")
      , noBreakTable = noBreak.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).
         appendChild(table.cloneNode())
      , tableParent = table.parentNode
      , tableParts = table.children
      , partCount = tableParts.length
      , partNum = 0
      , cell = table.querySelector("tbody > tr > td");
            noBreak.className = "noBreak";
            for (; partNum < partCount; partNum++) {
                if (!/tbody/i.test(tableParts[partNum].tagName))

         noBreakTable.appendChild(tableParts[partNum].cloneNode(true));
            }
            if (cell) {
    noBreakTable.appendChild(cell.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode()).
           appendChild(cell
            .parentNode.cloneNode(true));
                if (!table.tHead) {
                    var borderRow = document.createElement("tr");

           borderRow.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).colSpan =  
              "1000";
                    borderRow.className = "borderRow";
                    table.insertBefore(document.createElement("thead"), 
           table.tBodies[0]).appendChild(borderRow);
                }
            }
            tableParent.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"), 
          table).style.paddingTop = ".009px";
            tableParent.insertBefore(noBreak, table);
        };
    else
        var formatForPrint = function (table) {
            var tableParent = table.parentNode
      , cell = table.querySelector("tbody > tr > td");
            if (cell) {
                var topFauxRow = document.createElement("table")
        , fauxRowTable = 
         topFauxRow.insertRow(0).insertCell(0).appendChild(table.cloneNode())
        , colgroup = 
         fauxRowTable.appendChild(document.createElement("colgroup"))
        , headerHider = document.createElement("div")
        , metricsRow = document.createElement("tr")
        , cells = cell.parentNode.cells
        , cellNum = cells.length
        , colCount = 0
        , tbods = table.tBodies
        , tbodCount = tbods.length
        , tbodNum = 0
        , tbod = tbods[0];
                for (; cellNum--; colCount += cells[cellNum].colSpan);
                for (cellNum = colCount; cellNum--; 
             metricsRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).
              style.padding = 0);
                cells = metricsRow.cells;
                tbod.insertBefore(metricsRow, tbod.firstChild);
                for (; ++cellNum < colCount;   
        colgroup.appendChild(document.createElement("col")).style.width = 
              cells[cellNum].offsetWidth + "px");
                var borderWidth = metricsRow.offsetHeight;
                metricsRow.className = "metricsRow";
                borderWidth -= metricsRow.offsetHeight;
                tbod.removeChild(metricsRow);
                tableParent.insertBefore(topFauxRow, table).className =                
                 "fauxRow";
                if (table.tHead)
                    fauxRowTable.appendChild(table.tHead);
                var fauxRow = topFauxRow.cloneNode(true)
        , fauxRowCell = fauxRow.rows[0].cells[0];
                fauxRowCell.insertBefore(headerHider,  
          fauxRowCell.firstChild).style.marginBottom = -
        fauxRowTable.offsetHeight - 
             borderWidth + "px";
                if (table.caption)
                    fauxRowTable.insertBefore(table.caption,  
         fauxRowTable.firstChild);
                if (tbod.rows[0])

     fauxRowTable.appendChild(tbod.cloneNode()).appendChild(tbod.rows[0]);
                for (; tbodNum < tbodCount; tbodNum++) {
                    tbod = tbods[tbodNum];
                    rows = tbod.rows;
                    for (; rows[0];              
         tableParent.insertBefore(fauxRow.cloneNode(true),     
    table).rows[0].cells[0].children[1].appendChild(tbod.cloneNode())
      .appendChild(row        s[0]));
                }
                tableParent.removeChild(table);
            }
            else
                tableParent.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"),  
         table).appendChild(table).parentNode.className = "fauxRow";
        };
    var tables = document.body.querySelectorAll("table.print")
  , tableNum = tables.length;
    for (; tableNum--; formatForPrint(tables[tableNum]));
         })();
      </script>
       </div>
       </form>
      </body>
```

Comment: please be specific when posting your question in SO. no one can read such a big post before answering you.

Comment: If you're still struggling with this, the main problem I see is that your table tag doesn't have `class="print"`. So you'll need to add that. You'll also want to delete the first JavaScript function (the one with the comment that says THIS FUNCTION IS NOT REQUIRED). If that doesn't fix it, then I'd probably have to see the actual table markup that asp.net is generating to know what the problem is.