# Assigning css to id that was made programmatically

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

Currently, I am grabbing an unknown number of rows from a database and writing to a table. Each table cell is given a unique ID from the database.

Is there a way I can access these IDs to apply a certain CSS attribute to them, i.e:

*`reader.GetString("id").Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background-color", "#e1e1e1");`*

Sorry, still new to this - for example:

```
string sql = "select * from test";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
conn.open
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
  q += "<tr><td id='" + reader.GetString("id") + "'>" + reader.GetString("name") + "</td></tr>\r\n";

    if (reader.GetString("name") == "test")
   {
    // This will not work - I need to reference the actual ID - how can I get this to work?
    reader.GetString("id").Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background-color", "#e1e1e1");
   }
}
```

Comment: are you showing these in a DataGrid? are the values being returned in a datatable ? is this using html table?  what is `reader` in your current context? if this is an SqlDataReader, No..but you can build the table the old fashion way.. here is a link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860490/show-data-in-asp-net-html-table reference the accepted answer on how to do this also you could use a string builder to build your dynamic `html tags`

Comment: Yes, the reader is the SqlDataReader and I am building the table the old fashion way (such as the link provided where I am build a string to be sent to the page). On a post back, I need to reference the IDs of the table cells to highlight certain things via the Attributes.CssStyle.Add - however, since these IDs are built realtime, the code does not know about them.

Comment: can't help if I can't see code in regards to what you are doing / wanting to accomplish.. update the question and post relevant code.. then add comments in the code when you edit your question to explain what you want to do and at what point.. best advice I can give without seeing what it is you're currently doing

Comment: Thanks for your help! Still new to this - hopefully I put enough info - thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building HTML in the string `q`, so you also have to add the color definition inside `q`. The simplest way is something like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  var id = reader.GetString("id");
  var name = reader.GetString("name");
  // define style using the ? ... : ... operator
  var style = name == "test" ? "background-color: #e1e1e1" : "";
  q += "<tr><td id='" + id + "' style='" + style +  "'>" + name + "</td></tr>\r\n";
}
```

Note that building long strings tends to get slow, because each new addition will repeatedly make a copy of all text you had thus far + the new text.

A usually more efficient way is using a StringBuilder:

```
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
while (reader.Read())
{
  var id = reader.GetString("id");
  var name = reader.GetString("name");
  var style = name == "test" ? "background-color: #e1e1e1" : "";
  sb.AppendLine("<tr><td id='" + id + "' style='" + style +  "'>" + name + "</td></tr>");
}
// use sb.ToString() for the result
```