# SqlDataReader is not returning any data but query works

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

i have a problem with extracting data from MSSQL database. When i write the statement using SQL studio it works fine and returns over 500 records, but readers result is always empty.

Here's my code atm.

```
internal static void GetEntities(EntityRequest request, ref EntityResponse response)
    {
        string connString = @"server=DESKTOP-MCPU420\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Skyline;Integrated Security=True";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {

                string query = null;
                if (request.Expression.OrderBy == null)
                    query = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2};",
                        request.Expression.Columns, request.Expression.TableName, request.Expression.Where);
                else
                    query = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} ORDER BY {3};",
                        request.Expression.Columns, request.Expression.TableName, request.Expression.Where, request.Expression.OrderBy);

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn))
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                            response.Content.Add((IDataRecord)reader);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorMessageProvider.SetResponseMessage(ref response, ErrorList.PROGRAM_FAILED, request.Language);
            response.ErrorMessage = e.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This query goes in:

```
SELECT Id
    ,IATACode
    ,AgentName
    ,CASSCode
    ,HomeAirport_Id
FROM dbo.CLI_Agent
WHERE IATACode LIKE '%'
    AND AgentName LIKE '%'
    AND CASSCode LIKE '%';
```

And result from SQL studio
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJiXA.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure (can you debug this?) this line is working: response.Content.Add((IDataRecord)reader);  should be more look like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860490/show-data-in-asp-net-html-table

Comment: Can you show us the parameters that you passed?

Comment: What does `Response.Content.Add` do? If it stores the incoming object, rather than reading all the columns, that won't work, because the `IDataRecord` interface of `DataReader` just provides you with a view of the current record. When the reader is gone, this "data record" will cease to have any content.

Comment: Your SQL looks right, but you have and additional problem, you are not closing the connection.

Comment: Is it not entering the `while (reader.Read())`?

Comment: @bradbury9: `using` takes care of that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `using` is sugar candy for `IDisposable`, disposes the resource but does not try to close the connection.

Comment: @bradbury9: It seems to me the OP tries to add an object with interface IDataRecord (which contains some methods to get the data) to the HTML body. I´m pretty sure that this can´t work.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor probably, but OP says that reader is empty, which could mean that the reader has no records, or that is trying to show them poorly (what you and Jeroen pointed out)

Comment: @bradbury9: [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close#Anchor_3) disagrees, as does my experience. I hope I don't have to go all the way down to the source (because `SqlConnection` is annoyingly split across files) but take a disassembler to it if you don't believe me -- `Dispose` calls `Close` (unless called from a finalizer, of course). Explicitly calling `Close` isn't wrong, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Indeed "_Therefore_, _you_ _must_ _explicitly_ _close_ _the_ _connection_ _by _calling_ _Close_ _or_ _Dispose_." Didnt know that the sqlconnection Dispose implementation did close it also. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @WynDiesel parameters are actually empty at this time as you can see in that SQL query i've posted, that is what gets executed on database.

Comment: @Jaroen Moster Yeah i will change that in the future, the problem is, reader.Read() returns false so no records are added into the collection anyway...

Comment: You should check if the line "response.Content.Add((IDataRecord)reader);" executed or not. You cannot read any value after leaving the scope of using statement. Therefore; you should read all the values inside using statement.

Comment: @ali As i said earlier, it leaves at the start of while loop, because reader.Read() == false, so that line of code is irrelevant now

Comment: If `reader.Read()` returns false, then the query returned no results. Really it didn't! Use SQL Profiler to confirm that the correct query is going out, and do the usual "is this thing on" checks to verify you're running on the correct database. A less likely possibility is a view or table with row-level security that filters based on the account used. Finally, you may wish to extract this code into its own project (if you haven't done already) and use `Content.WriteLine` or something equally simple that cannot be subverted by other code malfunctioning, or your debugging messing up things.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Guys i feel like i am repeating myself... Yes the correct query goes in, i've tested it with profiler as well. The query works fine on DB end. But for some reason reader stays empty every time. I will try using blank project just in case.

Comment: "When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth." If the code is exactly this, if the query is what you expect it to be, if it's going to the right database and SQL Server is returning results, then the compiler or the debugger would have to be malfunctioning. You could eliminate that possibility by compiling different code (by,  for example, extracting this bit into a new project -- did you do that yet)? I can assure you `SqlDataReader` works for other people, so there's something specific to *your* setup that's not working right.

Answer (score 0):

There was a slight problem with connection string. I fixed it and now it works. It always comes down to the kinds of mistakes :-)

New conn. string:

```
string connString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-MCPU420\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Skyline;Integrated Security=True;";
```